# How to count the number of joins between a user and several tables?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgresql 9.3.9 and have a table `users` that looks like this:

```
user_id   | email
----------------------------
1001      | hello@world.com
1030      | mel@hotmail.com
2333      | jess@gmail.com
2502      | peter@gmail.com
3000      | olivia@hotmail.com
4000      | sharon@gmail.com
4900      | lisa@gmail.com
```

I then have several tables that list what users are connected on various platforms and when they connected. Ie `platform_a`, `platform_b`, `platform_c`, etc.

`platform_a` may look like this:

```
user_id | created_at
----------------------------
1001    | 2015-04-30
2333    | 2015-05-15
3000    | 2014-02-15
```

`platform_b` may look like this:

```
user_id | created_at
----------------------------
1001    | 2015-06-30
2333    | 2015-07-02
4900    | 2015-07-03
```

`platform_c` may look like this:

```
user_id | created_at
----------------------------
1001    | 2015-08-16
1030    | 2015-07-03
3000    | 2015-09-01 
4000    | 2015-09-01
```

I want the end result to look like this:

```
user_id | # of connections | latest created_at  | connected to a | connected to b | connected to c
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1001    | 3                | 2015-08-16         | yes            | yes            | yes
1030    | 1                | 2015-07-03         | no             | no             | yes
2333    | 2                | 2015-07-02         | yes            | yes            | no
2502    | 0                |                    | no             | no             | no
3000    | 2                | 2015-09-01         | yes            | no             | yes
4000    | 1                | 2015-09-01         | no             | no             | yes
4900    | 1                | 2015-07-03         | no             | yes            | no
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make an union with all your tables :

```
SELECT user_id, created_at, 1 AS a, 0 AS b, 0 AS c FROM tableA
UNION 
SELECT user_id, created_at, 0 AS a, 1 AS b, 0 AS c FROM tableB
UNION 
SELECT user_id, created_at, 0 AS a, 0 AS b, 1 AS c FROM tableC
```

then group the result from this subquery

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(user_id), MAX(created_at), MAX(a), MAX(b), MAX(c)
FROM subquery_above
GROUP BY user_id
```

This won't give you the zero results, but you can achieve that with a LEFT JOIN on the user list.

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
    user_id, 
    count(p), 
    max(created_at),
    coalesce(sum((pl = 'a')::int), 0) connected_to_a,
    coalesce(sum((pl = 'b')::int), 0) connected_to_b,
    coalesce(sum((pl = 'c')::int), 0) connected_to_c
from users u
left join (
    select *, 'a' pl from platform_a
    union all
    select *, 'b' pl from platform_b
    union all
    select *, 'c' pl from platform_c
    ) p
using (user_id)
group by 1;

 user_id | count |    max     | connected_to_a | connected_to_b | connected_to_c 
---------+-------+------------+----------------+----------------+----------------
    1001 |     3 | 2015-08-16 |              1 |              1 |              1
    1030 |     1 | 2015-07-03 |              0 |              0 |              1
    2333 |     2 | 2015-07-02 |              1 |              1 |              0
    2502 |     0 |            |              0 |              0 |              0
    3000 |     2 | 2015-09-01 |              1 |              0 |              1
    4000 |     1 | 2015-09-01 |              0 |              0 |              1
    4900 |     1 | 2015-07-03 |              0 |              1 |              0
(7 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

While you check for *all* users, it's typically fastest to aggregate before you join:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT user_id FROM users) u  -- subquery to clip other columns
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) AS connections, max(created_at) AS latest_created_at
        , bool_or(pl = 'a') AS connected_to_a
        , bool_or(pl = 'b') AS connected_to_b
        , bool_or(pl = 'c') AS connected_to_c
   FROM (       SELECT user_id, created_at, 'a'::"char" AS pl FROM platform_a
      UNION ALL SELECT user_id, created_at, 'b'               FROM platform_b
      UNION ALL SELECT user_id, created_at, 'c'               FROM platform_b
      ) p1
   ) p2 USING (user_id)
ORDER  BY user_id;
```

Result is exactly as desired - except that `connections` is NULL instead of '0' in your example. Use [`COALESCE()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) in the outer `SELECT` if you need to convert that. I didn't, because `SELECT *` is so convenient.
If you are going to list all columns in the outer `SELECT` you can as well just use `users` instead of the subquery `u` to clip other columns.

[`bool_or()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) is the perfect aggregate function for the job.

There might be multiple links to one platform. This query still returns a single row per user.